# Website keeping Facebook access token alive

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Not a programming question but not sure where-else this can be asked:

My site posts on user's Facebook wall when specific events occur. Since Facebook token has a max of 60 days lifespan now, I'm wondering what would be the best practice to renew this access token. For example, should I send a email every 2 months asking the user to login to my site, and re-authorize Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since Facebook token has a max of 60 days lifespan now, I'm wondering what would be the best practice to renew this access token.

Obviously, it requires user interaction – after all, that’s the whole point of deprecating offline_access. (I guess from your question that you know that, mentioning it anyway.)

> For example, should I send a email every 2 months asking the user to login to my site, and re-authorize Facebook?

That would be one way to go about it.

Another way would be, assuming your app users are regular visitors of facebook.com, to send them a [notification](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-notifications/). Upon clicking on that, the are send to your app’s canvas page – where you can get a new short-lived access token immediately by simply calling the JavaScript SDK’s `FB.getLoginStatus`. Send that to your server, extend it … and you’re good to go for another 60 days.

(You might not have a canvas page for your app – but this could be a good reason to set one up, even if it’s sole purpose would be the process described above.)

Apart from that, you should check if you actually *need* a *user* access token for what you’re doing. Many things can be done with your *app* access token also, as long as your app has the relevant permissions from the user (f.e. posting to wall, reading data, etc.)

Comment: ohhh i see...i guess my question would be, the App access token that allows posting to user's wall --- would it show up the same as if the user posted him/herself? We need to post a picture on the wall with description, and also we want the post to appear genuine unlike a spam. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can extend an `access_token` by using the endpoints discussed in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/)